# How do I create/use app specific configuration fields for an Android application?

Tags: android, mdm

## Background

I've been developing an Android application and have reached the point of thinking about how it will be used beyond just whether it works. Namely I'm looking at how the customer is going to distribute and configure the application. This had led me to Mobile Device Management (MDM) and Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) but I'm out of my depth as a developer and have no local resources (this is our first time producing an app).

## What I'm Trying To Do

I would like the capability for an administer to configure the application so that an everyday user cannot change it on the fly.

## What I've Found

One thought was for me to create my own account system in the app, but that seems redundant. So I started looking at management solutions and have started several trials. In one of these (and only one), once I've added my app to the "inventory" I have the option to configure it which opens a page of settings for that app. Below are some of the options for Chrome:
[image: Chrome Settings]

## What I'm Looking For

How do I define options like those at a code level?

As a follow up, should I? I've only figured out how to access those options in 1/6 EMM tools. If they're not commonly supported/standard then they're not going to actually solve my problem once this app is fielded.

I can't imagine I'm the first person to have this problem, but I can't find any existing questions/resources/documentation on configuring apps. If anyone has recommendations to can point me at references I'd greatly appreciate it.